# Serialization methods to create a custom cross-platform file format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a .NET 4.0 application for which I'd like to create a custom file format to serialize:

- A data table (that can be big)
- Custom classes (containing string and numeric properties, enumerations, and lists of classes)
- Images

I'd like to make this file format evolving in the future (by adding properties, images, etc). I also need this file format to be readable on other platforms, like Android and iOS in case I create a mobile app in the future.

I've seen several similar questions, and most of the solutions suggest to use Protocol Buffers, JSON, XML, or a lightweight SQL RDBMS like SQLite.

What I've not often seen in these questions is the topics of the license and the compression. 
As I will distribute my application as a commercial product, I would like to use a .NET library that allows to be included in a commercial product.
And as the file format will include a data table that can be big, I would need a method with a good compression rate.

Can you please help me to find the best solution for my needs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would advise avoiding thinking of serialization of "tables". Think instead of things like lists of homogeneous typed entities. You can always add members to those entities later (most serializers are fine with that). In terms of minimal overheads and open licensing, I humbly submit that protobuf-net would be a reasonable choice - it is an implementation of google's "protocol buffers" specification, designed to be efficient on the wire, and version tolerant (especially when adding members). That leaves compression; now: since the wire format is already very terse (it is a dense binary format, using just numbers for field identifiers - not names), it doesn't actually contain any "compression" as such; however, **if** your data is dominated by text (long descriptions, etc), then yes: it is still posible to shave some bytes - but you can do this by treating serialization and compression as separate - and just run it through something like `GZipStream`. Since `Stream` in .NET can act as a decorator, this is usually trivial, i.e.

```
using(var target = GetTheUndrelyingStream())
using(var zip = new GZipStream(target))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(zip, obj);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your input. I'm thinking of serialization of "tables" because my application is opening data files from various sources in form of System.Data.DataTable objects, which never have the same columns. That's why it would help me a lot if a method could automatically serialize a data table, without having to code typed entities for each data table. I note your suggestion of handling the serialization and compression as separate. Maybe having a zipped file format containing the serialized data and possibly additional files can be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

JulienVan,

When looking at software licenses to be used commercially my company tends to favor MIT and BSD. These licenses allow for commercial use and distribution without too many restrictions.

There are many guides to licensing, here is one I think is decent:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/14/understanding-copyright-and-licenses/

Generically speaking, serializing your message in JSON is more efficient than XML. I use the Newton library for commercial purposes for three reasons. It's fast, has a MIT license, and available from via NuGet.

Check it out here:
http://json.codeplex.com

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information about licenses. So when you use a component under MIT license, you just basically add the full copyright notice in your software documentation? I'll remember your advice about better using JSON over XML. How would you serialize the System.Data.DataTable object with the Json.NET library in order to be able to deserialize it easily with another language on another platform?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but I will say I make sure credits are in the code and if documentation is included have link to a credits page. Some companies using your software will ask for open source references and want to know if it's export compliant so it's good to have those answers handy.
As to separating your concerns about serialization and compression, I agree with Marc above. I use lists for everything.  The only exception is images which I just started putting in Azure Blob Storage.  This gives you two advantages, your data is much smaller and it allows for lazy loading of images.